# How to do maths in if and else in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

### **Hello guys!**

I have been trying to create a `if/else` statement code in `jQuery` but I guess my `if/else` statement is ***resting in peace***! I don't know what is getting wrong I have did everything and still it is not working correctly! Ok, here is my problem list ~

1. My `if/else` is getting inverse!
2. And I think everything is just getting messed up!
3. JsLint (in [jsFiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net)) is showing no error in my jQuery code!

Please here is my problem demo link ~~~~~~~~~~

[**PROBLEM DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/aj49m/)

Here is my smaple `jQuery` code ~~~~~~~~~

```
$(function () {

  var correct = '10';
  var incorrect = '9';

  $('div.correct_incorrect').css("background",function () {

      if( correct > incorrect )
      {
         return "#796";
      }
      else if( correct == incorrect )
      {
         return "#345";
      }
      else
      {
         return "#732";
      }

  });
});
```

Please help me out!

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Sorry to bother guys but my previous question is solved but I'm having a new problem with this code. Here I'm trying to retrive a value from two `input` elements! But it is not working.

Please have a look here ----

**[PROBLEM DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/aj49m/8/)**

**THANKS IN ADVANCE** (for this one too!)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `correct` and `incorrect` are strings. You can change them to integers to fix your problem:

```
                  var correct = 10;
                  var incorrect = 9;
```

Alternatively, you can use `parseInt(myNumAsString, 10)` to convert a string to a number at runtime.

Comment: Hey can you check this one too. As I'm having a problem with this one.
http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/aj49m/8/
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try using `parseInt`, like this:                      `var correct = parseInt($('input.correct_answers').val(), 10);`
                      `var incorrect = parseInt($('input.correct_answers').val(), 10);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the single-quotes from around your `correct` and `incorrect` variables. Currently, they are being treated as strings, not integers.

```
var correct = 10;
var incorrect = 9;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aj49m/1/

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings. It should be like this (without quotes):

```
var correct = 10;
var incorrect = 9;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed use integers instead of strings:

http://jsfiddle.net/aj49m/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing string literals '10' and '9' instead of integer values 10 and 9.
'9' is bigger than '10' when comparing strings.

Comment: I mean '9' is greater than '10' the same way as 'b' is greater then 'a'.